# defining multi branching nested tree in python recursively

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I am trying to implement some basic recursive structure in Python, but without great success. I have a tree represented in form of nested lists like this:

```
ex = ['A',
      ['A1',
       ['A11', 'tag'],
       ['A12', 'tag'],
       ['A13',
        ['A131', 'tag'],
        ['A132',
         ['A1321', 'tag'],
         ['A1322', 'tag']]]],
      ['A2', 'tag'],
      ['A3',
       ['A31',
        ['A311', 'tag'],
        ['A312', 'tag']],
       ['A32', 'tag'],
       ['A33',
        ['A331',
         ['A3311', 'tag'],
         ['A3312', 'tag']]],
       ['A34', 'tag'],
       ['A35',
        ['A351', 'tag'],
        ['A352',
         ['A3521', 'tag'],
         ['A3522', 'tag']]]],
      ['A4', 'tag']]
```

and I have defined a Node class that allows specifying a tag `'A', 'A1', ...` and adding children. Terminal nodes can be retrieved by noticing that `children` is not a list.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, tag, parent=None, children=[]):
        self.tag = tag
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = children
        self.is_terminal = False if isinstance(children, list) else True

    def add_child(self, node):
        if not isinstance(node, Node):
            raise ValueError("Cannot append node of type: [%s]" % type(node))
        if self.is_terminal:
            raise ValueError("Cannot append node to terminal")
        else:
            self.children.append(node)
```

Now I am having trouble implementing a function that would recursively transform the list-based tree into a Node-based one:

```
tree = Node(tag='A', 
            children=[Node(tag='A1',
                           children=[Node(tag='A11',
                                          children='tag'),
                                     Node(tag='A12',
                                          children='tag'),
                                     ...]),
                      ...])
```

This is my attempt so far based on the idea that at each position in the nested list, we might have either a terminal node, in which case we just add it to the root, or a non-terminal, in which case we extract the respective root tag and iterate over children recursively. When list is empty we return control to caller. 
My feeling is that the coding style is perhaps not the best suitable for Python, but I would like to know what I am missing more concretely.

```
def is_terminal(e):
    return len(e) == 2 and type(e[0]) == str and type(e[1]) == str

def from_list(lst, root):
    lst = list(lst) # avoid mutating input list
    if not lst:
        return
    for e in lst:
        if is_terminal(e):
            tag, children = e
            print "terminal", tag, "with root", root.tag
            root.add_child(Node(tag=tag, children=children, parent=root))
        else:
            e = list(e)
            tag, children = e.pop(0), e
            print "non terminal", tag, "with root", root.tag
            root = Node(tag=tag, parent=root)
            from_list(children, root=root)
```

It has a number of problems. For instance, it looses track of the highest root `'A'` -i.e. `A2` gets `A1` as root. It also flattens out the tree to a Node with 16 children, one per terminal node, and goes into infinite recursion.
I'd appreciate any type of hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the problem, which turned out to be partially a missing point in the algorithm and partially a misunderstanding in the way Python lists work.

The algorithm was loosing track of the highest root, because I wasn't adding the sub root in the `else` statement. This new version solves the issue.

```
else:
    e = list(e)
    tag, children = e.pop(0), e
    print "non terminal", tag, "with root", root.tag
    subroot = Node(tag=tag, parent=root)
    root.add_child(subroot) #
    from_list(children, root=subroot)
```

The problem with the flattening was actually the fact that I was using `[]` as default argument in the `Node` class definition. As explained [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/), the default empty list is being created only the first function call (or class instantiation in this case) and not every time the function is called.
Therefore, the children list of the root was getting added all sub children (and hence the flattening effect), and the children list of all sub children was getting modified every time the root children list was modified - hence the infinite recursion.

It turns out to be more of a Python-gotcha, rather than an algorithm definition problem.

For the record, the complete corrected version of the code:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, tag, parent=None, children=None):
        self.tag = tag
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = [] if not children else children
        self.is_terminal = False if isinstance(self.children, list) else True

    def add_child(self, node):
        if not isinstance(node, Node):
            raise ValueError("Cannot append node of type: [%s]" % type(node))
        if self.is_terminal:
            raise ValueError("Cannot append node to terminal")
        else:
            self.children.append(node)

def is_terminal(e):
    return len(e) == 2 and type(e[0]) == str and type(e[1]) == str

def from_list(lst, root):
    lst = list(lst)
    if not lst:
        return
    for e in lst:
        if is_terminal(e):
            tag, children = e
            print "terminal", tag, "with root", root.tag
            root.add_child(Node(tag=tag, children=children, parent=root))
        else:
            e = list(e)
            tag, children = e.pop(0), e
            print "non terminal", tag, "with root", root.tag
            newroot = Node(tag=tag, parent=root)
            root.add_child(newroot)
            from_list(children, root=newroot)
```

And here is how you call it:

```
root = Node(tag=ex[0])
from_list(ex[1:], root=root)
```